# Adding an array to a JSON object if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON object:

```
var collection = {
    "123":{
      "name": "Some Name",
      "someArray": [
          "value 0",
          "value 1"
       ]
     },
    "124":{
      "name": "Some Name"
     },
```

I have a method that updates and returns the collection like:

```
function updateCollection(id, property, value){
return collection;
}
```

Suppose the method call is like this:

```
updateCollection(124, someArray, "value 3");
```

How should I update? What I already wrote is:

```
function updateCollection(id, property, value){
  if(collection[id].hasOwnProperty(property)){
    collection[id][property].push(value);
  }
  else{
   //need help here 
  }
  return collection;
}
```

Expected Output after calling method `updateCollection(124, someArray, "value 3");` should be:

```
"124":{ "name": "Some Name", "someArray": [ "value 3", ] }
```

Comment: `collection[id] = [value];`?

Comment: What is the expected output for `updateCollection(124, someArray, "value 3");`?

Comment: expected output after the call updateCollection(124, someArray, "value 3"); should be:"124":{
      "name": "Some Name",
      "someArray": [
          "value 3",
       ]
     },

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new array with just `value` and assign it to `collection[id][property]`:

```
function updateCollection(id, property, value) {
  collection[id] = collection[id] || {}; // if "id" doesn't exist in collection
   if (collection[id].hasOwnProperty(property) {
      collection[id][property].push(value);
    } else {
      collection[id][property] = [value]
    }
    return collection;
  }
```

Comment: No, this answer does not handle the case where the collection does not contain the property id. In this case your code will raise an exception. Have a look at the the answers posted by Nina and Prabu which cover this case. I also came to a similar solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/WittigMarcus/v1xey2s6/

Comment: @Marcus I'm well aware of that. OP's question doesn't indicate that they are going to send an `id` which doesn't exist in `collection`. Answers are based on the assumption that OP has provided a [mcve]. If it is a possibility, OP has to mention that in the question. OP doesn't mention that this function is taking closure over the `collection` object either, but it's assumed `collection` object exists. [Is it expected to give code snippets that cover edge cases?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379897/is-it-expected-to-give-code-snippets-that-cover-edge-cases)

Answer (score 2):

I would go a step ahead and insert a new object for any `id` which does not exist and create a new array for `property`, if necessary.

```
function updateCollection(id, property, value) {
    collection[id] = collection[id] || {};
    collection[id][property] = collection[id][property] || [];
    collection[id][property].push(value);
    return collection;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated you code and it should work better for cases with not existed array or values

```
var collection = {
    "123":{
      "name": "Some Name",
      "someArray": [
          "value 0",
          "value 1"
       ]
     },
    "124":{
      "name": "Some Name"
     }};
function updateCollection(id, property, value) {
  if (collection[id] && collection[id][property]) {
      collection[id][property].push(value);
    }
    else
    {
    collection[id] = {};
      collection[id][property] = [value]
    }
  return collection;  
  }



  updateCollection(124, "someArray", "value 3");
  updateCollection(125, "someArray", "value 3");
  console.log(collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your code.

```js
var collection = {
"123":{
  "name": "Some Name",
  "someArray": [
      "value 0",
      "value 1"
   ]
 },
"124":{
  "name": "Some Name"
 }
 };

 function updateCollection(id, property, value){
  var _coll = collection.hasOwnProperty(id) ? collection[id] : {};
  _coll[property] = value;
  collection[id] = _coll;
  return collection;
 }

 console.log(updateCollection(124, "somearray", ['1','2']));
```